# create a new model instance automatically in django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am creating a django + react.js project. I have integrated social auth for google using django social auth. I am able to get the django access token and in the admin panel I can see a new User instance is getting created. However I have a UserProfile model which has a one-to-one relation with the User model and there no new instance is getting created. Following is my model class for UserProfile.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
userName = models.CharField(max_length=26,unique=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,unique=True)
profilePhoto = models.ImageField(default="/default.png")
rank = models.CharField(max_length=26,default="Novice")
def __str__(self):
    return self.userName
```

My question is, Is there any way that I could automatically create a new instance for UserProfile just whenever a new User instance is getting created.

Comment: Through signals, but that often is not a good idea. Why not just do that in the view where you create a user?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways.

One is to subclass the `save()` method on the first object. In this case, if it's the `User` model provided by Django, that's probably a bad idea, because it would involve modifying Django source code.

The second, is to use the `pre_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/) on the `user` object to create a `userprofile` object with the appropriate OneToOne relation, if the user instance that is about to be saved does not already have a `userprofile` object. Pretty much l[ike this.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#connecting-to-specific-signals)

There's a third possibility which doesn't really answer the question, but you can write a utility function `get_user_profile(user)` which creates one if it doesn't yet exist. Then, always use this to get a reference to your profile, rather than a direct reference to `user.user_profile`.